# wordpress Display Authors Twitter

Tags: wordpress, twitter

I would like to display the authors twitter on the single page where it says By "Author".

Here's what I am currently using:

```
By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> (<?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter' ) ) : ?>
<a href="<?php the_author_meta('twitter' );?>" target="_blank">Follow On Twitter</a>
<?php endif; ?>)
```

I would just like to change the "Follow on Twitter" bit to show that users @twitterusername, the link works with going to the twitter page, just would like it display that username?

Example: worldinsport.com/froch-vs-groves-ii-agreed

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You can use `<?php the_author_meta('user_email'); ?>` to get twitter userid

```
By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> (<?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter' ) ) : ?>
   <a href="<?php the_author_meta('twitter' );?>" target="_blank">
       Follow On Twitter  <?php the_author_meta('user_email'); ?>
  </a>
<?php endif; ?>)
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta

Comment: Hi, that just displays the users email address, I would like it to display the users twitter username?

Comment: Done it, used: <?php the_author_meta( 'wp-to-twitter-user-username' ); ?>, need wptotwitter plugin installed though.